# Incorrect simultaneous operation of OpenMP and MPIR in VS 2015

Tags: openmp, mpir

Guys. I'm trying to speed up the loop using OpenMP.

If I speed up a loop that uses an integer variable, then everything works correctly:

```
  void main()
{
    //mpz_class i("0");
    //mpz_class k("1");
    //mpz_class l("1211728594799");
    int k = 9;
    int i = 0;
    int l = 1998899087;

#pragma omp parallel for
    for (i=k; i <= l; i++) {
        if (i == 1998899085)
            printf("kkk");
    }


    system("pause");


}
```

If I start using the MPIR variable in a loop, then I get errors when building the program in Visual Studio 2015. Here are the numbers of these errors: C3015, C3017,C3019. Here is the code that causes these errors:

```
    void main()
{
    mpz_class i("0");
    mpz_class k("1");
    mpz_class l("1211728594799");
    //int k = 9;
    //int i = 0;
    //int l = 1998899087;

#pragma omp parallel for
    for (i=k; i <= l; i++) {
        if (i == 1998899085)
            printf("kkk");
    }


    system("pause");


}
```

MPIR itself works correctly if I disable pragma omp parallel for then the code is going to be fine, but it works much slower than using int variable of the same range of numbers.

What should I do to make Open MP work correctly with MPIR and I could speed up my program by running it in parallel?

Comment: I expect that OpenMP objects to the use of iteration variables which are not of one of the intrinsic integral types.

Comment: For those of us without visual studio, it would be interesting if you post the actual error messages. They're likely to give us all good hints

Comment: Hi Harald.
Error C3015 - invalid initialization in the For statement of the OpenMP directive.

Error C3017 - Invalid type of completion check in the For statement of the OpenMP directive.

Error C3019 -invalid increment in the For statement of the OpenMP directive.

As far as I can tell, open mp can not work with gmp variables inside a loop.

Comment: Here is the information from MSDN: // C3015.cpp
// compile with: / openmp
int main ()
{
    int i = 0, j = 10;
  
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
       #pragma omp for
       for (; i <0; i + = j) // C3015
       // Try the following line instead:
       // for (i = 0; i <0; i ++)
          --j;
    }
}